# Which OAuth flow to choose in Docusign: AuthCode or JWT?

Tags: docusignapi

In my usecase, admin users create documents and send them off to users for signature. All the admin users use a single organization account. I am confused about which OAuth flow to go with here: JWT or AuthCode.

Comment: Authcode it will make it easier in the future if you need add more supprot\

Answer (score 0):

I would think you could choose Auth code Grant, but not 100% sure of all your requirements.

Here is our official guidance:
[image]
https://developers.docusign.com/platform/auth/

Answer (score 0):

The users share a "single organizational account" -- you mean a "system" user account such as "sales@example.com"?

Authorization Code grant would mean that the users would be sharing a common password with each other. That's ok but not great. So I'd lean a bit towards JWT where the app handles the authentication to the common user account.